# How do I tell gitit plugins where the libraries are?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

### Short version

I configured `gitit` to use its “Deprofanizer” plugin, but when I ran it, it failed, saying:

```
Loading plugin 'plugins/Deprofanizer.hs'...

plugins/Deprofanizer.hs:6:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Network.Gitit.Interface’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
6 | import Network.Gitit.Interface
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
gitit: Error loading plugin: plugins/Deprofanizer.hs
```

Apparently it found the plugin, but then couldn't compile it.

How do I fix this?

### Longer detailed version

I've installed [the `gitit` wiki software](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) according to [the instructions](https://github.com/jgm/gitit/blob/master/README.markdown#compiling-and-installing-gitit), using `stack install`.  If I just run `gitit`, it works perfectly: it creates its `static` directory, initializes its database, and runs an HTTP service on port 5001, just as advertised.

But I can't get the plugins to work, for what seems to be a purely configuration-related issue.

[The sample `gitit` configuration](https://github.com/jgm/gitit/blob/master/data/default.conf) contains an explanation of how to configure plugins:

```
plugins:
# specifies a list of plugins to load.  Plugins may be specified
# either by their path or by their module name.  If the plugin name
# starts with Gitit.Plugin., gitit will assume that the plugin is
# an installed module and will not try to find a source file.
# Examples:
# plugins: plugins/DotPlugin.hs, CapitalizeEmphasisPlugin.hs
# plugins: plugins/DotPlugin
# plugins: Gitit.Plugin.InterwikiLinks
```

The default configuration uses no plugins.  Several plugins are supplied with `gitit`, and the instructions here seem clear, so I tried turning on the `Deprofanizer` plugin by changing the `plugins` configuration to:

```
    plugins: plugins/Deprofanizer.hs
```

as the sample suggested.  ([`Deprofanizer` is provided with `gitit`](https://github.com/jgm/gitit/blob/master/plugins/Deprofanizer.hs) as an example.)

This *almost* works.  When I start up `gitit`, it does locate the Deprofanizer module where I expect, and it attempts to compile it.  But:

```
Loading plugin 'plugins/Deprofanizer.hs'...

plugins/Deprofanizer.hs:6:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Network.Gitit.Interface’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
6 | import Network.Gitit.Interface
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
gitit: Error loading plugin: plugins/Deprofanizer.hs
```

The `Network.Gitit.Interface` module is indeed part of the Gitit distribution, and I suppose it is compiled into my `gitit` executable.  But I don't know why the plugin can't import it, or how to fix it.  I can't find any hint in the manual that this might be a problem.

I found the code ([in `Network.Gitit.Plugins`](https://github.com/jgm/gitit/blob/master/src/Network/Gitit/Plugins.hs#L38) responsible for loading and compiling the plugin module:

```hs
    loadPlugin pluginName = do
      logM "gitit" WARNING ("Loading plugin '" ++ pluginName ++ "'...")
      runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
          ...
```

and instrumented it to write out the value of `libdir`, which is `/home/mjd/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.5/lib/ghc-8.6.5`.  This directory exists, but I don't know what to do with it.

So again, the question is:

> How do I fix this?

Comment: I followed the instructions, and installed using `stack install`. Then I turned on the plugin for `Deprofanizer.hs` per the instructions, ran `gitit`, and the wiki page opened just fine; no error message. You may have to provide more details, such as what operating system, version, etc.

Comment: Somewhere in `.stack/programs` is an executable named `ghc-pkg`. (`stack` itself may be willing to run it for you via `stack exec ghc-pkg` without having to find it yourself.) What does `ghc-pkg list gitit` say? What about `ghc-pkg check`? Perhaps the library is not as installed as you intended for some reason.